# Let $h(t)$ be a continuous function. Show that if $X_n \xrightarrow{D} X$, then $h(X_n) = O_p(1)$

Tags: probability, convergence, asymptotics

My initial thought on proving this was to use the continuous mapping theorem to conclude $h(X_n) \xrightarrow{D} h(X)$ and then use the fact that convergence in distribution implies tightness in probability. Is this the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: That's perfect.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!